# Filling in 3d Shapes

Tags: java

For a college project I need to draw an empty cube and then show the cube being filled.

So far I have heard that JME and voxels is the way to go but I have no idea where to start. Can anyone point me towards a tutorial or any reading?

My project is in Java but any pseudo-code is welcome.

Comment: You need to explain in greater depth. What does "show the cube being filled" mean? Being filled with water? Being filled with smaller cubes? Be really specific. Also I don't think that this is game-dev material.

Comment: My apologies. I mean being filled with smaller cubes, and using this idea I am supposed to create a smartphone game.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Wolfire Games Blog entry about voxelization of one of their complex rabbit meshes, you can findt it [here](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/11/Triangle-mesh-voxelization).

I think it'll give you some insights on how can be the voxelization process performed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read so far, I think these jMonkeyEngine would be a great candidate for this. If you want to jump right into it, LWJGL is also an excellent choice.

But for the idea itself, you will most likely have to use specific coordinates that will be looped through to be filled with the smaller cubes.